# Stored Procedures - To pass two values to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
create proc coursenames 
 @course varchar(30), @In varchar(20) 
as 
select fname, lname
from student
where course = @course
and lname like @In+'%'
```

The last line of this code `and lname like @In+'%'`, I am not entirely sure what it does?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a like clause there are two placeholders possible.

- `%`
- `_`

The `%` means "any number of characters, 0 or more`

The `_` means "one character".

The `@In+'%'` concatenates the string in `@In` and the `%`, which means that the column starts with whatever in `@In` is and ends with whatever or is just the string in `@In`.

Another example:

```
foo like '%ab_d'
```

searches for all rows where the foo column starts with anything and ends with for example "abcd" or "abxd"

Answer (score 0):

It means select all students with name has the In prefix

Answer (score 0):

It is used to filter records `where lname is starting with what you pass in @In and anything after that.` Please read this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for better understanding

For example if you pass `@In = 'Ja'` and your `lname` records are as below

```
lname
------
Jackson
James
Robert
```

Your select results with `lname like @In+'%'` will be lnames starting with `'Ja'` like below. (ie; `'Robert'` *filtered out* as it is not starting with `'Ja'`

```
lname
------
Jackson
James
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL the % symbol is used for wild card searches. Basically, the last line of your code is asking for any records that have the last name beginning with whatever the @In parameter is. The % symbol allows the LIKE in the query to look for the text you supplied and any text that occurs after it.  If you put the % symbol before the @In parameter you would get back any records where the last name ends with whatever @In is; correspondingly if you put '%' + @In + '%' in your query it will return records where @In occurs anywhere within the string